# Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

this is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptBasket" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DeleteItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="Utility.GetProductUrl(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("productID")),Eval("productName").ToString(),Eval("SKU").ToString())"><%#Eval("productName") %> </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Basically I want to pass data to `GetProductUrl` method which is coming from the repeater control.

Comment: Error sounds like ASP.Net not Classic ASP but there isn't enough code to know for sure.

Comment: now check i posted properly

Comment: That is debatable...See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: basically i want to pass data to GetProductUrl method which is coming from repeater control

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, you're not using `Eval()` in the context of a databound control.  Since you're not showing us in what context you *are* trying to use it, there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: David i am using repeater controller over here and under repeater control i use this method to get url by pass values which coming from repeater controll

Comment: @OWAISkhan: When you say "over here" we can't see what you're pointing at.  We're not actually in the room with you.

Comment: @David i am using repeater control of classic Asp.net and eval values from repeater control and i am trying to pass these values into GetProductUrl() method.

Comment: @OWAISkhan: (1) Carriage returns and other formatting make code more human-readable, which helps when you want humans to read your code. (2) ASP.NET is not Classic ASP. (3) Unless something has recently changed, this code doesn't appear valid at all.  An `ItemTemplate` should contain the markup for the repeater item, not server-side code.  You can still use server-side code in server tags, but not directly in the markup.  I wouldn't expect this code to produce the given error, I'd just expect it to render to the page as plain text.

Comment: @David check more understandable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use server-side code directly in your page markup:

```
<a href="Utility.GetProductUrl(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("productID")),Eval("productName").ToString(),Eval("SKU").ToString())">
```

This won't work, and is invalid for a number of reasons.  (For starters, how would one even expect any parser to know how to handle nested double-quotes like that?)

Note how you correctly use server-side code elsewhere in your markup:

```
<%# Eval("productName") %>
```

You have to use that same notation *anywhere* that you want to use server-side code.  For example:

```
<a href="<%# Utility.GetProductUrl(Convert.ToInt16(Eval("productID")),Eval("productName").ToString(),Eval("SKU").ToString()) %>">
```

The `<% %>` tag is how the parser identifies server-side code to process when building the page output to send to the browser.

Comment: Its work @David thanks